# How do you select distinct() models based on a specific column with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database in which I store documents - some are independant from each other, but some are just a "next version" of a previous document. In that case, I store the id of the latest version in a column.

An example dataset would be like this:

```
id | name       | version | validated | latest_version_id
 1 | 'Doc 1'    |       1 |      true | null
 2 | 'Doc 2'    |       1 |      true | null
 3 | 'Doc 3 v1' |       1 |      true |    5
 4 | 'Doc 3 v2' |       2 |      true |    5
 5 | 'Doc 3 v3' |       3 |     false |    5
```

I would like to be able to select all *validated* documents in their *latest* version. Typically a request that would return lines 1, 2 and 4 in the dataset.

I was hoping to be able something like `Docs::where('validated', true)->distinct('latest_version_id')->get()` but it's obviously not as simple as that..

Any query guru to point me in the right direction? A solution would be to get all results and then filter out some models, but that doesn't sound very optimized.

Comment: You can be try this package: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset . I think it can resolve your problem.

Comment: Edit the question and add an example of what you want to get from the dataset

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have trouble because there is no unique way (that I can see) to identify that a doc is related to another doc. I.E. `Doc 3 v1` is the same document as `Doc 3 v2` *to a human*... but how does the app know this? How does it search to know which are common and thus to check for the latest version of this particular doc?

I think your best solution may be if you can slightly re-architect the way you have stored data, to provide possibly an FK to a set of docs, you can solve this.  This way, a 'documents table' would allow for a query to know specifically which docs are the same.  Then, your existing table above would have an FK `doc_id` in addition to the existing `name` column.  Thus, you eliminate the problem of various names (they would all be attached to the same master document by FK).  This will then allow you to show what version corresponds to that particular master document and which set that versions belongs to, and then you can distinctly manage the query much easier based on these parameters.

Comment: Thanks - I am not sure I understand what the difference would be between having a FK to identify a "document set", vs the current architecture where a 'document set' is identified as rows having the same 'latest_version_id'. Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Sure.  I can see where you were going with the `latest_version_id`,and that makes sense for a very small table.  But, it makes the query more complex in that you have to look for null as well as try to join the table on itself (circular) to be able to find which doc fits which set of versions.  If you have a dedicated table for documents, and *this* existing table from above is for validated  / versions attached to those FKs, your query can be *much* simpler and directly pull what you want, which is to find latest version of the doc-set for those validated.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the Watercayman, you should think about refactoring. In the short term, you can use the following, but it's not 100% reliable but it will achieve what you want with your current dataset

```
  $unversioned = Doc::query()->whereNull('latest_version_id')->where('validated', true);
  $versioned = DB::table(DB::raw("(SELECT * 
                                   FROM docs WHERE latest_version_id IS NOT NULL AND validated = true 
                                   ORDER BY version DESC) as t"))
                            ->groupBy('latest_version_id');

  $unversioned->union($versioned)->get();
```

Please note models should be singular - which is why I've called Doc:: rather than Docs::

Comment: +1 from me.  Good solution to a complex task.  But having that circular `latest_version_id` is going to cause him problems pretty quickly due to the unnecessarily complex architecture, I think.

Comment: I agree it should be rearchitected.